# Dynamic access to a dynamic endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am coding a spring-mvc webapp and I am integrating spring-security to handle all user-related stuff for authorization. I'm doing a university-like system (where you can login and see your courses, announcements, etc) but the problem is the following: I have two types of roles, one that is declared under the users table (either the user is or is not an admin) and then there's a relation between a user and a course (and it's role in the course, e.g Student, Teacher, etc).

The problem is that depending on the course I am at (let's say /course/5) a user can (or can't, depends on the relation userId | courseId | roleId) be a teacher (and for example a teacher inside a course should be able to post announcements), so I should find a way to get that courseId from the URL, make a call to the DAO to get what is the current logged-in user role within that course and make a decision based on that (for example, redirect to a JSP view that has more functionality than a student one should have).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you have two ways to do this:

1. Implement a custom filter to be added to the authentication / authorization chain that checks this. The downside of this approach is that you need to know which DAO to call based on the request which might not be a nice piece of code. Additionally, in the case that the user is authorized to that course you will most probably call the DAO twice (during authorization and later in your business logic). Additional details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter.
2. You can check this before applying your regular business logic. In your service that handles the HTTP request, you would check if the user is authorized to that course and if it is not you throw an exception or any other way you see fit. The advantage of this is that you don't duplicate calls to DAO (getting the course details). The downside is that your authorization logic would mingle with your regular business logic. Although some may disagree I find this acceptable, since checking if a user is authorized to a course is somewhat also part of your regular business logic.

Having said all that, I would go with the 2nd option.

Comment: thanks for the answer, a friend of mine recommended me to have a look into AccessDecisionVoter but i still think your second approach is the correct one, plus using an AccessDecisionManager filters every url instead of the ones i want to specifically evaluate so idk if its the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Never heard before of `AccessDecisionVoter` but it seems to me to be a custom filter with a different name :). Of course, there are differences as the `AccessDecisionVoter` seems to be indeed interesting and abstracting away some of the complexity of creating and registering a custom filter. Nevertheless, I would go with the second approach. It is simpler, easier to understand and in fact works.